# Why is Enumerator.MoveNext not working as I expect it when used with using and async-await?

Tags: c#, list, async-await, ienumerable

I would like to enumerate through a `List<int>` and call a async method.

If I do this in this way:

```
public async Task NotWorking() {
  var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};

  using (var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator()) {
    Trace.WriteLine(enumerator.MoveNext());
    Trace.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);

    await Task.Delay(100);
  }
}
```

the result is:

```
True
0
```

but I expect it to be:

```
True
1
```

If i remove the `using` or the `await Task.Delay(100)`:

```
public void Working1() {
  var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};

  using (var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator()) {
    Trace.WriteLine(enumerator.MoveNext());
    Trace.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
  }
}

public async Task Working2() {
  var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};

  var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();
  Trace.WriteLine(enumerator.MoveNext());
  Trace.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);

  await Task.Delay(100);
}
```

the output is as expected:

```
True
1
```

Can anyone explain that behavior to me?

Comment: I *expect* this is a mutating value-type problem; one moment

Comment: @MarcGravell It is, just inspected the generated IL.

Comment: Yeah, due to `enumerator` being hoisted as a field

Comment: The difference when using the `using` block is that the enumerator has to survive to cross to the other side of the `await` fence, and is thus lifted to a field. Without `using` this does not happen, and thus it "works". - https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2010/05/19/why-enumerator-structs-are-a-really-bad-idea/

Comment: A lazy "fix" is to use `IEnumerator<int>` instead of `var`; this means the enumerator will be boxed, but boxed and working is better than not boxed and broken

Comment: Mutable structs are evil™

Comment: Do you want to write up an answer or should I?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen still, correct me if I'm wrong, but the compiler *could* have used `ldflda` to execute against the mutating instance? I haven't ran the IL, but I guess it is using the `ldfld`/`stloc`/`ldloca` dance?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen feel free; I haven't even decompiled it yet ;p

Comment: You're right in about the instructions used, don't know why it doesn't generate `ldflda` instead. Perhaps this is just stock IL generation that doesn't get a chance to be told to do otherwise when in a async/await method.

Comment: confirmed: `L_0065: ldfld valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List\`1/Enumerator\`0<int32> ConsoleApplication21.Program/<NotWorking>d__1::<enumerator>5__3
    L_006a: stloc.s enumerator
    L_006c: ldloca.s enumerator
    L_006e: call instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List\`1/Enumerator\`0<int32>::MoveNext()` - bleugh

Comment: This is a compiler bug. The struct being stored as a field does not matter. The C# spec says that this does not happen so it's a bug.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's the short of this problem. A longer explanation follows.

- [`List<T>.GetEnumerator()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yss765(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a struct, a value type.
- This struct is mutable ([always a recipe for disaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil))
- When the `using () {}` is present, the struct is stored in a field on the underlying generated class to handle the `await` part.
- When calling `.MoveNext()` through this field, a copy of the field value is loaded from the underlying object, thus it is as though `MoveNext` was never called when the code reads `.Current`

As Marc mentioned in the comments, now that you know of the problem, a simple "fix" is to rewrite the code to explicitly box the struct, this will make sure the mutable struct is the same one used everywhere in this code, instead of fresh copies being mutated all over the place.

```
using (IEnumerator<int> enumerator = list.GetEnumerator()) {
```

---

So, what happens *really* here.

The `async` / `await` nature of a method does a few things to a method. Specifically, the entire method is lifted onto a new generated class and turned into a state machine.

Everywhere you see `await`, the method is sort of "split" so that the method has to be executed sort of like this:

1. Call initial part, up until the first await
2. The next part will have to be handled by a `MoveNext` sort of like an `IEnumerator`
3. The next part, if any, and all subsequent parts, are all handled by this `MoveNext` part

This `MoveNext` method is generated on this class, and the code from the original method is placed inside it, piecemeal to fit the various sequencepoints in the method.

As such, any *local* variables of the method has to survive from one call to this `MoveNext` method to the next, and they are "lifted" onto this class as private fields.

The class in the example can then *very simplistically* be rewritten to something like this:

```
public class <NotWorking>d__1
{
    private int <>1__state;
    // .. more things
    private List<int>.Enumerator enumerator;

    public void MoveNext()
    {
        switch (<>1__state)
        {
            case 0:
                var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
                enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();
                <>1__state = 1;
                break;

            case 1:
                var dummy1 = enumerator;
                Trace.WriteLine(dummy1.MoveNext());
                var dummy2 = enumerator;
                Trace.WriteLine(dummy2.Current);
                <>1__state = 2;
                break;
```

This code is *nowhere near the correct code*, but close enough for this purpose.

The problem here is that second case. For some reason the code generated reads this field as a copy, and not as a reference to the field. As such, the call to `.MoveNext()` is done on this copy. The original field value is left as-is, so when `.Current` is read, the original default value is returned, which in this case is `0`.

---

So let's look at the generated IL of this method. I executed the original method (only changing `Trace` to `Debug`) in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) since it has the ability to dump the IL generated.

I won't post the whole IL code here, but let's find the usage of the enumerator:

Here's `var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator()`:

```
IL_005E:  ldfld       UserQuery+<NotWorking>d__1.<list>5__2
IL_0063:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Int32>.GetEnumerator
IL_0068:  stfld       UserQuery+<NotWorking>d__1.<enumerator>5__3
```

And here's the call to `MoveNext`:

```
IL_007F:  ldarg.0     
IL_0080:  ldfld       UserQuery+<NotWorking>d__1.<enumerator>5__3
IL_0085:  stloc.3     // CS$0$0001
IL_0086:  ldloca.s    03 // CS$0$0001
IL_0088:  call        System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Int32>+Enumerator.MoveNext
IL_008D:  box         System.Boolean
IL_0092:  call        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine
```

[`ldfld`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldfld%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) here reads the field value and pushes the value on the stack. Then this copy is stored in a local variable of the `.MoveNext()` method, and this local variable is then mutated through a call to `.MoveNext()`.

Since the end result, now in this local variable, is newer stored back into the field, the field is left as-is.

---

Here is a different example which makes the problem "clearer" in the sense that the enumerator being a struct is sort of hidden from us:

```
async void Main()
{
    await NotWorking();
}

public async Task NotWorking()
{
    using (var evil = new EvilStruct())
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        evil.Mutate();
        Debug.WriteLine(evil.Value);
    }
}

public struct EvilStruct : IDisposable
{
    public int Value;
    public void Mutate()
    {
        Value++;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

This too will output `0`.

Comment: You should mention that this is a compiler bug. It sounds as if this was a problem with the code.

Comment: @usr that's quite a complex thing to comment on (would require lots of specification references)
, and ultimately whether or not it is a compiler bug: doesn't help the user

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm pretty sure the spec does not say that method calls behave differently when an unrelated await or using is introduced in some totally different place... It's important to know that this is a bug so that the user knows he must "wiggle" the code around until the bug disappears and leave a comment.

Comment: The fix proposed here works but only by chance. All it does is trigger a different compiler code path. A different compiler might do this differently.

Comment: I will post a complete code example, and I will post a Connect issue as well. I too believe this is a bug.

Comment: @usr the box fix isn't "by chance", nor does it trigger a different compiler code path. It works by avoiding the *mutating value-types* problem

Comment: This code should just work. Mutating value types are not at fault here. Their behavior is clearly specified. No special care at all is required.

Comment: The presence of `using` muddles the code here, the fact that the value type is lifted is not enough.

Comment: Posted a Microsoft Connect issue here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1200553

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a bug in the old compiler, possibly caused by some interference of code transformations performed in using and async.

Compiler shipping with VS2015 seems to get this correctly.

Comment: Happened to me today in VS 2017 Pro using C# 7. The project targets .NET 4.5.2, though, so not sure if that makes a difference.